# Python regex extract lines between substrings that start with certain criteria

Tags: python, regex, string, findall

I've edited this to be more clear and provide a solution.

I'd like to use regex to search within substrings for text starting with the characters `--` and extract all text that comes after for that line. I already have both pieces successfully working separately (1. the substring search and 2. the `--` search), I'm just not sure how to combine these effectively. I have a string -

```
qry = ''' 
with 
qry_1 as ( -- some text
   SELECT ID, 
          NAME
   FROM   ( ... other code...
),
qry_2 as ( 
    SELECT coalesce (table1.ID, table2.ID) as ID,
           NAME
   FROM (...other code...
),
qry_3 as (
-- some text
     SELECT id.WEATHER AS WEATHER_MORN,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id.SUN
                ORDER BY id.TIME) AS SUN_TIME,
            id.RAIN,
            id.MIST
   FROM (...other code..
-- some other text
)
'''
```

1. I'm able to extract subquery information through `re.findall` here -

```
sub = re.findall('\),\s{2,}(.*?)as\s\(',qry)
```

2. And the special character search

```
re.findall(r'--+(.*)(.\s)',qry)
```

3. To ultimately use to search between strings for the commentary.

But how to incorporate step 3 successfully?

Thank you for guidance here

Comment: I'd start by processing the string line-by-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 3 successfully run

```
commentary = [re.findall(r'--+(.*)(.\s)', i) 
     for i in re.findall('\),\s{2,}(.*?)as\s\(',qry,flags=re.S)]
```